# Changing Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I recently modified my ActionBar as to have two tabs, corresponding to two Fragments respectively.

Let's say my first tab is the Main Page, the second my About Page.

The About Page is static.

The Main Page changes. Let's say, for question's sake, that the Main Page has this single button in the center of the screen. I want it in such a way that when the user clicks the button, the page changes to another screen with text. This is easily done with Activities using Intent. I don't know how to do this with Fragments.

In sum, what is the best practice switching Fragments inside a tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using fragment's method getChildFragmentManager().

So your way to go.

In you first tab

Create nested fragment whitch will display button.

```
MainPage.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />



</LinearLayout>

class MainPage extends Fragment(){

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ButtonFragment(), ButtonFragment.class.getName());
     ft.commit();


     ((Button)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.your_button)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(View v){
  FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new TextFragment(), TextFragment.class.getName());
ft.addToBackStack(TextFragment.class.getName());
     ft.commit();
      }

})

}

public boolean onBackPressed(){
FragmentManager mn = getChildFragmentManager();

if(mn.getBackStackEntryCount()>0) 
                mn.popBackStack(man.getBackStackEntryAt(0).getName(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
}



class ButtonFragment extends Fragment(){

.....

public void onCreateView(Bundle savedinstance){
//inflate you view with button here

}
```

Comment: Can you explain the last bit... the ButtonFragment class?

Comment: You have two fragments is you actionbar navbar(MainPage, DetailsPage). MainPage also contains inner fragment with button (Main Page has this single button). After you press it, inner fragment is replaced by another one

Comment: I'm starting to get it now. Thank you so much, Greensy. :)

Comment: np, do not forget to replace getFragmentManager() to getSupportFragmentManager() is you use suportlibrary or ABS

Comment: maybe one of u can help me im having problems changing what the current fragment displays... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578543/android-change-fragment-page

Comment: Greensy, sorry to disturb you, but ((Button)findViewById(R.id.your_button)) is returning an error for me. It's saying findViewById is undefined for the type MainPage.

Comment: R.id.your_button - should be the id, that you defined in xml layout. And also, my bad, you should replace findViewById() to getView().findViewById() or getActivity().findViewById()